# If $\varphi_t$ is a diffeomorphism for each $t\in I$ then is $\phi(x,t):=\phi_t(x)$ derivable with respect the last coordinate?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, manifolds, partial-derivative

So let be $M_t$ a $k$-manifold of class $C^r$ in $\Bbb R^n$ for each $t\in I\subseteq\Bbb R$ and thus let be $\varphi_t:U_t\rightarrow V_t$ a coordinate patch of $M_t$ so that choosing for each $t\in I$ a such coordinate patch and supposing -only for sake of beauty- that
$$
U_{t_1}\cap U_{t_2}=\emptyset
$$
when $t_1,t_2\in I$ are distinct -if this does not hapens we can alway traslate one of them- we define a function $\phi$ through the equation
$$
\phi(x,t):=\phi_t(x)
$$
for each $(x,t)\in\bigcup_{t\in I}\big(U_t\times\{t\}\big)$. So clearly
$$
\frac{\phi(x+h\cdot\hat e_i,t)-\phi(x,t)}{|h|}=\frac{\phi_t(x+h\cdot\hat e_i)-\phi_t(x)}{|h|}
$$
for each $i=1,...,n$ so that the function $\phi$ is derivable with respect the first $n$ coordinates because $\phi_t$ is for each $t\in I$ a diffeomorphism. However I do not be able to prove that $\phi$ is derivable with respect $t$ too: so could someone clarify if this is true or false? Moreover if it is true then how prove it? Finally I observe that generally the domain of $\phi$ is not open so that I ask if ask if requiring that
$$
U_{t_1}=U=U_{t_2}
$$
for any $t_1,t_2\in I$ - if this does not hapens we can alway shrink $U_t$ to a cube and so translate- then the result holds although it does not holds with the original hypothesis. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is false.

Comment: Okay, coud you give a counterexample?

Comment: It's been a while; I don't recall it.  A good answer will come along I'm sure....

Comment: Okay, I am waiting for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a basic counter example for $M = \mathbb{R}$:
$\phi(x,t) = \begin{cases} x & \text{ if } t \geqslant 0\\
-x & \text{ if }  t <0 \end{cases}$ is not differentiable with respect to $t$, while $\phi_t$ is a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ (and hence a coordinate patch) for all $t$.

Comment: Clearly it is not differentiable with respect $t=0$, right?

Comment: Yes, the problem occurs at $0$

Comment: Only a last question: if $\phi$ is not derivable with respect $t$ generally (right?) however is it continuous, right? Indeed it seem to me that $\phi$ is derivable with respect the $n$ first coordinates and its $n$ first derivatives are continuous by assumption so that $\phi$ must be continuous.

Comment: However I am not sure about the correctdness of my argumentation.

Comment: $\phi$ is not continuous, because it is not continuous on the point of the form $(x,0)$ for $x \neq 0$.

Comment: Okay. So generally $\phi$ is not continuous; but your $\phi$ is continuous.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro No, my $\phi$ is not continuous. For example, $\phi(1,t)$ does not have a limit at $t=0$

Comment: Oh, right! Indeed $$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}\phi(1,t)=1\neq-1=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^-}\phi(1,t)$$ so that the discontinuity follows.

Comment: Moreover for sake of completness $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\phi(x,h)-\phi(x,0)}h=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{x-x}h=0\neq\pm\infty=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{-x-x}h=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{\phi(x,h)-\phi(x,0)}h$$ provided $x\neq 0$ so that $\phi$ is not derivable with respcet $t=0$ when $x\neq 0$, right?

Comment: Yes, this looks correct

Comment: Okay, answer approved. Thanks very much for your asssistance.

Answer (score 3):

Why should $\phi_t$ be smooth with respect to $t$?

First off, you cannot expect to prove anything if $U_t \cap U_s = \emptyset$ for $t \ne s$, since then even the difference $\phi_t(x) - \phi_s(x)$ is never defined. So drop that assumption and assume $U_t = U_0$ for all $t$.

Counterexample with this assumption: $I = [0,1], \, M_t = S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ for all $t$, $U_0 = (-1,1)$, and define $\phi_t:U_0 \to S^1$ for $0 \le t \le 1$ as
$$
\phi_t(z) = \begin{cases} (z, \sqrt{1-z^2}) \quad (t \in \mathbb{Q}) \\
(z, -\sqrt{1-z^2}) \quad (t \notin \mathbb{Q}) 
\end{cases}
$$
Then for any $x \in U_0$,  $t \mapsto \phi_t(x)$ is measurable in $t$ and no better.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much for the counterexample! Anyway I do not see precisely why $ϕ_t$ is a coordinate patch and so I have only one question: how prove it? is it necessary to know Lebesgue integration? Sorry for my ignorance but I studied only riemaniann integration theory.